# Spring writing logs to console

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j

In my spring boot application I am writing logs using logback.xml as per below. Expected output lines are around 20 millions.

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJavaClass.class);
  logger.info("3000 characters strings to be logged go here.");
```

I have my logback.xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
     
    <appender name="RollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>out.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %-50logger{40} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
         
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>out-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>10MB</totalSizeCap>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
     
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="httpclient" level="WARN" /> 
</configuration>
```

And my application.properties has:

```
logging.file.name=log.log
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name=MyApp-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
logging.file.max-size=1MB
logging.file.total-size-cap=10MB
logging.file.max-history=30
logging.file.clean-history-on-start=true
```

The logs are written to the log.log file and console both.

**Question:**
Is it a good idea to throw 20 million lines to console?
Am I going to over-burden the system by this approach and I should disable the console logs completely?

Comment: If it's going to your console, you'll know *immediately* if you're running into performance issues.  I would argue that 20 million lines of logs is ***horrendous*** log practice, since you're not getting anything of actual value from the logs at that point.

Comment: Great. I loved this word "horrendous". It says all  :-). Thanks a lot @Makoto.